# is there a way to set after_commit callbacks to a specific ActiveRecord transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions, activesupport

I am creating a ActiveRecord transaction this way

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  MyModel.create!(name: "value")
  OtherModel.create!(name: "value")
end
```

I'd want to set a specific `after_commit` callback to this transaction. I don't want to attach it to any one of the models because I don't it to be executed every time I create one of these separately.

I cannot simply write some code in the end of the `transaction` block either, because maybe the real transaction is created outside of this code (I am not setting the `require_new` option to `true`)

Is there any way to set callbacks to a specific transaction instance?

thank you very much

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to add them to the model? That is the rails thing to do, and I don't think it's possible to do what you are proposing. However, we can probably find a way to work around whatever reason you have for not wanting to touch the models.

Comment: you can wrap the transaction in a `begin` `rescue` block, and put the after_commit call right after the transaction. If the transaction fails, the block will be rescued and the callback won't be called.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at these gems:

- [after_commit_everywhere](https://github.com/Envek/after_commit_everywhere) (disclaimer: I'm the author)
- [after_transaction_commit](https://github.com/instructure/after_transaction_commit)